# Delete Row from Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to go through an array to find duplicate entries in a single column of that array and delete the entire row.

I am getting figuring out `rangeStart`, `rangeEnd`, and `lastrow` above this and that part is working fine.

```
data = Range(rangeStart, rangeEnd)

For i = lastrow - 1 To 2 Step -1
    If data(i - 1, x) = data(i, x) Then
        'Delete data(i)
    End If
Next
```

Any help with this would be awesome!

Comment: are your values in `Range(rangeStart, rangeEnd)` sorted?

Comment: Where is `x` coming from?

Comment: x is a unique identifier from above.

Comment: Easier to create a second empty array of the same size and copy only unique "rows" over.

Comment: How would I copy the entire row over to another array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub RemoveDups()
Const COMPARE_COL as Long = 1
Dim a, aNew(), nr As Long, nc As Long
Dim r As Long, c As Long, rNew As Long
Dim v As String, tmp

    a = Selection.Value
    nr = UBound(a, 1)
    nc = UBound(a, 2)

    ReDim aNew(1 To nr, 1 To nc)
    rNew = 0
    v = Chr(0)

    For r = 1 To nr
        tmp = a(r, COMPARE_COL)
        If tmp <> v Then
            rNew = rNew + 1
            For c = 1 To nc
                aNew(rNew, c) = a(r, c)
            Next c
            v = tmp
        End If
    Next r

    Selection.Value = aNew

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do what I need it to do!

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?:

```
If data(i - 1, x) = data(i, x) Then
    data(i,x).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Getting a Subscript out of range

Comment: `lastrow` should be equal to `(rangeEnd.row - rangeStart.row)`

Comment: @hstay - OP is not looping through a range (note there is no `Set` where they assign the range to `data`, so that line creates a 2-D array from the range values)

Comment: Thanks, @TimWilliams, I was blindfolded after seing Range().

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Excel's inbuilt Unique options (*Data  ... Remove Duplicates*)?

Another efficient `VBA` method is to use a `Dictionary`.

```
Sub A_Unique_B()

Dim X
Dim objDict As Object
Dim lngRow As Long

Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
X = Application.Transpose(Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))

For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    objDict(X(lngRow)) = 1
Next

Range("B1:B" & objDict.Count) = Application.Transpose(objDict.Keys)
End Sub
```